# Weird TCP connection on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

On Oracle Linux "Linux bjzv0880 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 7 17:01:44 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

I have 1 TCP Server and 2 TCP Clients running with the connection status below:

```
******[root]# netstat -anp | grep 58000
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:58000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3614/AppServer
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:44500 192.168.250.102:58000 ESTABLISHED 3673/AppClient1
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:44488 192.168.250.102:58000 ESTABLISHED 3631/AppClient2
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:58000 192.168.250.102:44500 ESTABLISHED 3614/AppServer
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:58000 192.168.250.102:44488 ESTABLISHED 3614/AppServer******
```

Then I forcefully stop the AppServer without cleaning up the socket. And make the AppClient* to try to reconnect to AppServer very quickly. After a little moment, I got a weird connection:

```
*[root]# netstat -anp | grep 58000
tcp 0 0 192.168.250.102:58000 192.168.250.102:58000 ESTABLISHED 3673/AppClient1*
```

Note: I have done a wireshark capture on the tcp communication, and from the traffic log
 1. there are 2 rounds of retries to connect from source port selected by OS
 2. In the 1st round, 58000 was not selected by OS
 3. but in the 2nd round, 58000 was selected and it happened to be able to established

How could it be possible? Appreciated for your advice.

Comment: could you check the process for the id 3673, because it looks like a zombie one or a daemon thread which has hanged up

Comment: not, it's not a zombie process.

Comment: then what you mean  that you forcefully stop the AppServer without cleaning up the socket ??

Comment: actually AppServer was kill with -9 and it has no chance to do the cleaning up.

Comment: Note: the AppServer and AppClients are running on the same Linux box.

Comment: so obviously you have unmanaged daemon threads running cause of the opened sockets